# HAVING Clause Issues in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am experiencing issues with my HAVING clause.
Explanation: Each orderno has at least one rxnum tied to it. But each rxnum can have multiple scripts (scriptitemcnt)'s. My problem is that I am trying to use a HAVING clause to **ONLY** pull orderno's that have the SUM of items less than or equal to 8. The query will execute, but it is still pulling orders that have item sum greater than 8. Here is my code:

```
SELECT
oh.orderno,
od.rxnum,
SUM(od.scriptitemcnt) as scriptitemcnt,
od.ndctopick,
od.drugdesc,
od.unitno,
od.status,
od.datetimefilled,
od.packingunit,
od.datetimepacked,
oh.totesideinorder

FROM
mck_hvs.oldorderdetails od with( nolock ),
mck_hvs.oldorderheader oh with( nolock )

WHERE
oh.orderno = od.orderno
and od.status != 5
and ( @dateFrom is NULL or od.datetimepacked >= cast( @dateFrom as datetime ) )
and ( @dateTo   is NULL or od.datetimepacked  <  cast( @dateTo as datetime ) + 1 )
and oh.totesideinorder = 'N'
and od.packingunit NOT IN (695, 696, 697, 698)

GROUP BY
oh.orderno,
od.rxnum,
od.scriptitemcnt,
od.ndctopick,
od.drugdesc,
od.rxnum,
od.unitno,
od.status,
od.datetimefilled,
od.packingunit,
od.datetimepacked,
oh.totesideinorder

HAVING 
SUM(od.scriptitemcnt) <= '8'

ORDER BY
oh.orderno asc,
od.rxnum asc
```

Comment: We don't have your tables and data. Try to simplify to a smaller (fewer columns) table and some sample data that still demonstrates the issue and then add that (and the simplified query) to your question, please.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the query you've posted.  You need to add a script that reproduces the problem or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: SUM(od.scriptitemcnt) <= '8'  Why '8' is string? It should be INTEGER rite?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy - whilst that is true; due to data type precedence it will be converted to a numeric datatype to match whatever data type `SUM` is returning before the comparison occurs.

Comment: I finally figured it out, I was pulling from the wrong column name this entire time. Thanks regardless! Turning the string into an integer was successful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems.  First, you're comparing the count against the string `'8'` instead of the number `8`.  Depending on how SQL server interprets things, that could result in numbers like `10` being treated as less than `8`.

Now that's the simple issue.  From your description it sounds like you want *orders* that have a total count not greater than 8.  If that's right, then the bigger issue follows...

When you use `GROUP BY`, aggregates (like `sum()`) count within a group.  Because you're showing (i.e. `SELECT`ing) - and therefore grouping by - the `RXNUM`, the sum is per `RXNUM`, not per order.  If you want to pull a record for each `RXNUM` but filter based on an aggregate for the entire `ORDERNO` it's a little trickier than what you're doing here.

You can use `SUM() OVER()` instead of `SUM()` as a starting point.  But IIRC this can't be used directly for filtering in sql-server, so you end up needing a subquery.  Something like

```
select *
  from (select oh.orderno, od.rxnum
             , sum(od.scriptitemcnt) over(partition by orderno) as order_scriptitemcnt
               -- other data
          from -- ...
       )
 where order_scriptitemcnt <= 8
```

Comment: "Depending on how SQL server interprets things" - this is **not** a deep mystery. There are data type precedence rules. And all of the numeric types are higher than the string types. By even suggesting this possibility, you're doing a dis-service to understanding.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - That's a nice opinion.  Here's another one that has more practical relevance: By suggesting that people should write code that depends on DBMS-specific precedence rules, *you're* doing a dis-service to programming.

Comment: It's practically impossible to write *good*, pure portable ANSI SQL code. The reality is that as soon as you're e.g. working with date/time data, you're going to be working with a specific dialect. Once you're working in a particular dialect, yes, I would suggest that you should familiarize yourself with that dialect, just as much as you would with an entirely new language. And part of learning any programming language should be at least an attempt to familiarize yourself with the rules of that language.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Writing to a dialect is an entirely different thing from deliberately and unnecessarily relying on non-standard behaviors.  Even when a behavior were standard, it shouldn't be used if it makes code less readable.  You are quite simply wrong.  I'm sorry you've fallen into the trap of thinking that knowing how a system will treat bad code somehow makes you a better programmer.